# How to enable GPU in Vertex AI Pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pytorch, gpu, google-cloud-vertex-ai, kubeflow-pipelines

I'm relatively new to Vertex AI Pipeline and I'm facing an issue where I'm unable to enable GPU utilization within my pipeline. Despite specifying the hardware type for a particular component, it still runs on the CPU, as indicated in the figure below. I suspect there might be a missing configuration in my pipeline setup.

```
embeddings_task = (
        generate_article_embeddings(
            transformer_model=TRANSFORMER_MODEL,
            article_dataset=articles.output,
        )
        .set_cpu_limit("32")
        .set_memory_limit("208G")
        .add_node_selector_constraint("NVIDIA_TESLA_T4")
        .set_gpu_limit("4")
    )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIWJP.png)

Could someone please provide guidance on how to correctly enable GPU utilization in a Vertex AI Pipeline?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've installed all the necessary GPU libraries to enable GPU acceleration, but when I run the code, it still defaults to using the CPU.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into a very similar issue, my CPU is at 100% utilization, but my GPU accelerator stays at 0%

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have installed the cuda dependencies in your base container.

I made this component for testing if the GPU was available using tensor:

```
@dsl.component
def simple(
    word: str,
    number: int,
) -> None:
    log.info("Running Simple")


    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        device = torch.device("cuda")  # set the device to be the first cuda device
        log.info("PyTorch is using the GPU")
        log.info("Current device: %s", torch.cuda.current_device())
        log.info("Device name: %s", torch.cuda.get_device_name(device))
    else:
        log.info("PyTorch is using the CPU")

    # Create a tensor on the CPU
    x = torch.randn(100, number)

    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        # Move the tensor to the GPU
        x = x.to(device)

    # Perform some computations on the tensor on the GPU
    y = x * 10**4

    # Move the tensor back to the CPU for printing
    y = y.to("cpu")
```